# Merging files with sox sequentially

Tags: audio, sox

I have seen posts where people merge multiple sound files into one outfile like: `soxmix in1.wav in2.wav in3.wav out.wav`.  However they are all on top of each other.  Is there a way to merge so that in2.wav play *after* in1.wav, instead of at the same time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with sox was a pain in the neck because you have to pad silence to the front of the individual pieces before the soxmix call, and it's quite hard to get the timing just right.

Instead I used [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), which lets you open a sound file, and add as many additional tracks as you want, and you can easily visually line up the end of file's track with the beginning of the next file's track.  Then you can just export.  Fast and easy.